# BIOS continously beeping with video mode 13h

Tags: assembly, x86-16

i wrote a small program in 16-bit NASM assembly for a boot sector (512 bytes). It uses BIOS video mode 13h to draw a little white stripe on the screen. This is the code:

```
bits 16
org  0x7C00

VIDEO_INT: equ 0x10
VGA_BASE: equ 0xA000

mov ax, 13        
int VIDEO_INT             
push VGA_BASE
pop es
xor di,di
mov ax, 255
mov [es:di], ax
mov [es:di+1], ax
mov [es:di+2], ax
start:


;--------------------------------------

; make file 512 bytes, just enough to fit in boot sector
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55 ; boot sector magic number
```

However, when compiled the program and tested it out on real hardware it produced the nice white stripe on screen, but the BIOS for some reason produced a continous PC speaker beep. Can anyone explain why this is the case, what im doing wrong, and what i should do instead?

Comment: What do you think happens after the last instruction in your code is executed?

Comment: Why? I dont know.

Comment: The processor does not know that your program ends there.  It just continues executing whatever junk there is in memory after your program.  But an instruction like `jmp $` in to make the code go in an endless loop and prevent this from happening.

Comment: Oh... alright. Anyways, is there a better way to write to video memory? This seems a bit confusing...

Comment: What do you mean by "a better way?"  Is being able to directly write pixel to the frame buffer not good enough?

Comment: As in simplicity. I dont want to use int 10h for putting pixels on the screen because its notoriously slow. But with 10h i atleast know what im doing. Here, however...

Comment: Well you have to compute the address of the pixel by the formula *y* × 320 + *x* (or so I think) and then just write to memory at that address in segment `A000`.  Doesn't seem to be too complicated.

Comment: Alright, so does this mean that if i wanted a pixel at y level 20 and x level 5, i would write at the memory address `0xA000 + 1620`? And if so, what would i set to give the pixel a color?

Comment: Well the other way round, you got *x* and *y* mixed up.  Also it's in segment `A000`.  So you need to load a segment register with `A000` and access memory using that segment register at the right offset.  Mode 13h is a palette mode with 256 colours (you can find the palette online).  It is also possible to set your own palette, but it's easiest to just use the predefined colours.

Comment: Since you're writing words (`ax`), you are setting two pixels (one to 255, which is white, the other to 0, which is black and the default value for all pixels when the video mode is set).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that the CPU [processor] doesn't know when to stop executing code, and so it just executes whatever next is in memory. To stop this, you just put a simple loop (for example: `jmp $`) at the end of your program so that the CPU just continuously loops over and over again and doesn't execute anything else anymore.

Comment: Better: Put a label like `halting:` followed by `sti` then `hlt` then `jmp halting`. This saves CPU time and power while looping infinitely.

Comment: Yeah... you can do that as well.